# Notes client shows error of when opening document via Notes URL

Tags: url, lotus-notes

I am having issues when I try to open a document via Notes URL `Notes://<SERVER>/<DB_UNID>/<VIEWD_UNID>/<DOCUMENT_UNID>`.

If I have Notes client already running it shows me error message of:

`Cannot complete the operation. Notes is running but not responding. Please close and restart Notes.`

But if Notes client is not started then the operation completes successfully with Notes client starting and document opens up within it. I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.3 with extension library installed from OpenNTF.

Anybody faced similar issue? Is there any setting that I need to make in order for this to work?

Comment: Do you get the same issue with the latest fix pack?

Comment: I have FP1 - `Release 8.5.3FP1 Revision 20120308.0840-FP1 (Release 8.5.3FP1)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd try all the 'normal' Notes troubleshooting steps. Delete the cache.ndk, bookmark.nsf etc, maybe backup and delete the workspace folder, reconfigure by wiping most of the notes.ini. If you aren't the helpdesk, you may want to contact them first.